# Why is jQuery not selecting all attribute elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, attributes

I am making tabs on a website and I set up jQuery to run function when any attribute is clicked(this is only to test out the selector, not all attributes will be used in the final website). None of the attributes will be selected after I get into a certain div.
Here is the html:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
     <div id="image" style="border:2px solid;float:left">...</div>
     <div id="backgroundInfo" style="margin-left: 5px;float:left">...</div>
     <br>
     <div id="medBackground" style="margin-left: 5px">...</div>
     <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
         <a> Clowns</a>
         <ul class="tab-links">
              <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">03/05/2001</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab2">06/05/2007</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content">...</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The list was generated using a while loop. All attributes are selected except for the ones in div(class = tabs).
Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
                jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I got this code from: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery#step-jquery
 If anyone could help me figure out what is going wrong that would be awesome. I got it to work in a simplified form but not in my main website.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w788e8t4/1/ - what is the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w788e8t4/2/

Comment: What is happening on your main website? Is it doing nothing at all? Maybe best if you step through the script with firebug or the Chrome developer tools to see where the script stops (if it does, otherwise you probably have a selection problem).

Comment: if you can edit the above fiddles to recreate your problem we might be able to help you

Comment: I used developer tools and the attributes which are in the div(class = tabs) are not getting an event. All other attributes have an event attached to them on developer tools.

Comment: Actually none of the attributes under divs(background, image etc.) under the content div are being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the .on() method wrong for a dynamically generated list,
try

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    //your code
});
```

Instead of

```
 jQuery('a').on('click', function(e)  {
     //your code
 });
```

Comment: I tried this and none of the attributes were selected.

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you so much! I was thinking it had to do with a dynamically generated list.